# Using imagemagick compare function in aws lambda with error code -9 and no error message

Tags: aws-lambda, compare, imagemagick

Not a question but a solution I stumbled upon after struggling for quite a while.

While using Imagemagick's "compare" function to compare two images in AWS lambda I kept getting an error code of -9 with no error message. I was not able to find discussions related to this issue any where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out compare uses quite a bit of memory, and the initial lambda setting of 128mb just doesn't cut it. Increasing lambda's memory solved the issue.

For reference - lambda prior to executing the compare function was using ~80mb, the two images being compared are ~2mb each. When running compare, memory usage jumped up to ~220mb